# preg_replace to nest string

Tags: php, preg-replace

In PHP, I have a set of string like

```
'various text code(01) various text'
```

and I want to turno them into

```
'various text <img src="images/code(01).png"> various text'
```

"code(XX)" can contain any number, like "code(99)" or "code(27)", etc., and I want that number to be maintained and nested into a  tag.

Can I use preg_replace to achieve this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'various text code(01) various text';
$str = preg_replace('/code\(\d+\)/', '<img src="images/$0.png">', $str);
print($str);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/95741

Comment: `$0` is preferred over `\0`.